# Unable to sync gradle files - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Can anyone please give me solution as I have download fresh Bumblebee Android studio and trying to create a sample project but it is unable to sync grade files and showing following error-
[image]

I have following gradle versions of wrapper.properties and plugin:

**wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

**app.gradle file:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you plz share all error with text not image

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Android Studio if it is being opened.
2. Delete cache in these folders:

> C:\Users\xxxxx\.gradle\caches

> C:\Users\xxxxx\.android\build-cache

> C:\Users\xxxxx\.android\cache

Comment: Not worked, I have tried it several times

Answer (score 0):

androidstudio -> file -> invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: not working already did.